# How can I download a blob image in react native for ios?

Tags: ios, react-native

I am developing an application, where I have a blob file which is an image, I am trying to download it, but I am not getting a solution, I am using expo.

I've tried react-native-fsblob, but it needs a react-native-link which I can't use, I don't know why.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.